# RMS speeds of two species of particle

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Consider a gas that is a mixture of two species of molecule, type 1 and type 2, with mass and mean number density has mass $m_1, n_1$ and $m_2, n_2$, respectively. After a long time, the gas is in thermal equilibrium, so the temperature of the two species is the same.

I am interested in the relative RMS speeds of the two species.

If the two species have the same temperature, I believe that means they have the same kinetic energy, so in a unit volume of gas, each species of gas has kinetic energy:

$$ E_i = \frac{m_in_i\langle v^2\rangle}{2}$$

Setting the two kinetic energies equal and solving, this gives relative rms values:

$$ \frac{v_1}{v_2} = \sqrt\frac{m_2n_2}{m_1n_1}$$

However, using $$\langle v_i^2 \rangle = \frac{3k_BT}{m_i} $$
and setting T equal for both species of particles yields relative rms values

$$ \frac{v_1}{v_2} = \sqrt\frac{m_2}{m_1}$$

Which argument is correct and why?

Comment: I suppose this is really a question of the definition of a mixture of gases having the same temperature; does it mean that each individual particle has the same Ek, in which case argument 2 is correct, or does each species as a whole need to have the same kinetic energy as the other, in which case it's argument 1.

Comment: At the same temperature, the average kinetic energy of a **single gas molecule** is the same for all gases.  The total kinetic energy of all the molecules in unit volume might not be the same for different gases, unless $n_1=n_2$.

Comment: I agree, the first assumption is wrong